# SQL Server query with repeated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lookup table (Table A) and a table that stores the actual values (Table B). The issue I'm facing is Table B can store multiple values (comma-separated) from Table A.

So if Table A has for example 2 columns:

```
Code   Value
------------
1      Dog
2      Cat
3      Bird
4      Bear
```

...and Table B can have something like this:

```
Record #     Code
--------------------
1            2
2            3,4
3            1,4
4            3
5            1,2,3,4
```

When I loop through Table B, I want my output to look like this:

```
Record #         Code         Value
-------------------------------------
1                2            Cat
2                3            Bird
2                4            Bear
3                1            Dog
3                4            Bear
4                3            Bird
5                1            Dog
5                2            Cat
5                3            Bird
5                4            Bear
```

In other words, I want a record from Table B to return as many times as many comma-separated values it has from Table A.

What is the best and the most efficient way of achieving this?

TIA,
-TS.

Comment: You need to include the tag for the DBMS type and the column types please

Comment: Any chance of refactoring (aka normalizing) your table design?

Comment: Hi @BShaps The TableA.Code = integer and TableB.Code = varchar

Comment: Hi @Philip, unfortunately I cannot normalize the table now.

Comment: What is the DBMS?  MySql, Postgres, etc.

Comment: Sorry, it's SQL

Comment: Did you mean MS SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's MS SQL

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have (or want) a Split/Parse function, here is an in-line approach

**Example**

```
Select A.[Record #]
      ,Code = B.RetVal
      ,C.Value
 From  TableB A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(A.[Code],',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Join TableA C on B.RetVal=C.Code
```

**Returns**

[image]